# Custom Image Gallery in Apostrophe CMS

Tags: apostrophe-cms

What are all the possible sizes for images?

Essentially, how do I get a list of images that have been "attached" to the page? I am trying to create my own image gallery since the default gallery is limited. Does that mean I should create my own widget that extends 'apostrophe-images-widgets'?

So once I do that, and add the widget to a page, and add images, how do I get the list of images? I want to get a thumbnail size, and a larger size of the image to be placed in a modal? What are all the possible sizes available?

Here is the code to show the default image gallery that ships with Apostrophe:

```
{%- for entry in data.widget._pieces -%}
  {%- set image = entry.item or entry -%}
  {%- set relationship = entry.relationship -%}
  <div data-slideshow-item class="apos-slideshow-item{% if loop.first %} apos-current{% endif %}{% block itemClass %}{% endblock %}" style="background-image: url({{ apos.attachments.url(image.attachment, { size: data.options.size, crop: relationship }) }})">
    {%- block title -%}
      <h4>{{ image.title }}</h4>
    {%- endblock -%}
    <img data-image src="{% block imgSrc %}{{ apos.attachments.url(image.attachment, { size: data.options.size, crop: relationship }) }}{% endblock %}"/>

  {%- endfor -%}
```

Here is the documentation for apostrophe-assets:      http://apostrophecms.org/docs/modules/apostrophe-assets/index.html

The documentation notes a few possible sizes, but it feels incomplete. I am not following how to request multiple URLs for multiple sizes of a single asset.

Comment: also, please don't flag this. there seems to be a bug with the wysiwyg editor on stack overflow because it refuses to indent my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the lead developer of Apostrophe at P'unk Avenue.

I think your goal is to change how `apostrophe-images-widgets` is rendered.

You can do that by creating `lib/modules/apostrophe-images-widgets/views/widget.html` in *your own project* (do not modify it inside node_modules, just make a parallel folder in your project).

Copy the `widget.html` file from Apostrophe's corresponding folder.

Then you can modify it as you see fit.

The available sizes are documented here:

http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/adding-editable-content-to-pages.html#code-size-code

Definitely take advantage of the provided utilities to correctly build URLs to them, the same way the stock `widget.html` does.

Of course, I'm sure you also want to change the player JavaScript. To do that, you'll create:

`lib/modules/apostrophe-images-widgets/public/js/always.js`

In your project. Copy and paste the original as a starting point. It's very short so I'll quote it here:

```
// example of a widget manager with a play method.
// You don't need this file at all if you
// don't need a player.

apos.define('apostrophe-images-widgets', {
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces-widgets',
  construct: function(self, options) {
    self.play = function($widget, data, options) {
      $widget.projector(options);
    };
  }
});
```

(btw you need to indent four spaces to quote code on Stack Overflow. I recommend doing so in a text editor and then copying and pasting. Works reliably for me.)

This default version invokes our "jquery projector" plug-in to animate a slideshow. You could remove that line in your copy (but keep at least an empty `self.play` method, so that you override our default implementation). Then there would be no animation at all. Or you can write your own logic.

The `$el` argument to `play` is a jQuery object referring to the relevant widget. Always use it to scope things with `find()`, resist the temptation to do everything with `$(...)` at the page level.

If you actually like our widget but want different behavior for some cases, you can extend it with a new name (in app.js):

```
modules: {
  'my-slideshow-widgets': {
    extend: 'apostrophe-images-widgets'
  }
}
```

Then you would create `lib/modules/my-slideshow-widgets`, and include `my-slideshow` in the widgets allowed in some areas and singletons around the site, but otherwise follow the same pattern as above.

See also:

http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/custom-widgets.html

For a really good introduction to creating entirely custom widgets.