# Image Slideshow Stop Function

Tags: apostrophe-cms

As stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41602949/custom-image-gallery-in-apostrophe-cms). I wanted to add a new function for the apostrophe-image-widget slide function but I'm no sure how to do exactly.

To explain it further I think it makes sense to have an stop function for the widget player which can be called like `data-next` or `data-previous` maybe `data-stop` would be good.

So my question is can I do it in:

```
// example of a widget manager with a play method.
// You don't need this file at all if you
// don't need a player.

apos.define('apostrophe-images-widgets', {
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces-widgets',
  construct: function(self, options) {
    self.play = function($widget, data, options) {
      $widget.projector(options);
    };
  }
});
```

And can I have maybe a little hint how to access these `data-next` functions and extend them as described ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the underlying jQuery plugin that Apostrophe's slideshow depends on does not support the feature you're asking about, you'd have to PR that functionality into the plugin (found here https://github.com/punkave/jquery-projector) and then PR the update into Apostrophe core.

Alternatively you could write your own `images` widget and bring your own slideshow plugin to the party. You'd initialize the slideshow plugin in your widget's player, similar to player snippet you pasted above.

A popular slideshow library many Apostrophe developers bring to projects is Swiper https://idangero.us/swiper

You can see an example implementation of Swiper in Apostrophe in the Open Museum project https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-open-museum/tree/master/lib/modules/slideshow-widgets

Comment: Nice! the source of the projector plugin is pretty clear... so I'll write an additional function for that if its even necessary, because I can use the `pauseOnClick` function for now. I wrote an additional image slider already but I still use for some other embedded cases my modified apostrophe-image-widget. Anyway with the source of projector I can work now thx a lot.